Vivaha Panchami
I want to find out scriptural or cultural references for the wedding day of Lord Rama and Sita Devi occuring on Shukla Paksha Panchami in the month of Margashirsha.
There is no reference to this in the Valmiki Ramayana, however in the Ramcharitamanas by Tulsidas Goswami, in the Bala Kanda, Doha 312, it mentions the month of Agrahayana which is Margashirsha, but no mention of Panchami tithi
